# AWK Duplicate subtitute

Tags: macos, awk, duplicates

Trying to use awk to substitute duplicated value by a "counter"

I have this example list: (there is duplicated mac ba484ebce594, but the duplicates wont be in the first and last spot usually)

```
ba484ebce594    1.107.86.38   null
641c67dc36da    1.107.86.39   as14Adrasna
84d47ec1e13a    1.107.86.40   asUBAViasua
5470d2af4cd8    1.107.86.42   asT12Maas2
5470d2af4f08    1.107.86.43   asTAceraslfScanner
641c67dc5e24    1.107.86.44   asTAceraslfAna
641c67dc3577    1.107.86.50   as15Halasa
e840f2502778    1.107.86.60   as13BIBasB
5470d2af4d43    1.107.86.61   as18BIBasB
5470d2af4cc9    1.107.86.62   as19BIBasB
5470d2af506e    1.107.86.63   as110BIasAB
5470d2af4b59    1.107.86.64   as111BIasAB
ba484ebce597    1.107.86.65   as1Funcasi
e840f2502659    1.107.86.66   as1BAL
ba484ebce594    1.107.86.68   as14Terasnal1
```

I am using the following script

```
awk '{ y[$1]++; print $0; if (y[$1] >= 2){printf("%012d", y[$1]-1); print "\t" $2 "\t" $3}}'
```

to find and substitute duplicate MACs with number of occurrences

Desired result:

```
ba484ebce594    1.107.86.38   null
...
e840f2502659    1.107.86.66   as1BAL
000000000001    1.107.86.68   as14Terasnal1
```

What I am getting:

```
ba484ebce594    1.107.86.38   null
...
e840f2502659    1.107.86.66   as1BAL
ba484ebce594    1.107.86.68   as14Terasnal1
000000000001    1.107.86.68   as14Terasnal1
```

Can anyone shed a light what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you're doing `print $0` in all cases...?

Comment: Yeah Same I was Also wondering that...

Comment: please update the question with a set of sample data (eg, 10 lines) that includes two different mac's that are duplicated (one with 2 entries, one with 3 entries) and then update the expected output to show what you expect; at this point I'm curious how you do the numbering when you have more than one duplicated mac address ... do you end up with a pair of duplicate `000000000001` entries?

Comment: what is your input field delimiter? it looks like you want a tab as the output field delimiter; is your input field delimiter also a tab or something else? it *looks* like you want to maintain the spacing between columns but this isn't guaranteed if you're using a different delimiter for input and output

Answer (score 2):

This is the essence of what you need:

```bash
awk '
    ++count[$1] > 1 {$1 = sprintf("%012d", count[$1] - 1)}
    {print}
' file
```

That will mess up the formatting, unless you can specify FS and OFS as tabs.

---

A version that preserves the existing whitespace

```bash
awk '
    ++count[$1] > 1 {sub(/^.{12}/, sprintf("%012d", count[$1] - 1))}
    {print}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the unmodified record in all cases. Assuming you have tab-separated fields you can try:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {y[$1]++} y[$1]>1 {$1=sprintf("%012d",y[$1]-1)} 1' file
```

But note that if you have more than 2 occurrences of the same MAC address you will have incrementing counts for all repetitions.

Comment: That´s expected I want for every repetition to have different values.